# Alpine.js Data isn't Updating

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

The value of `submitDisabled` isn't affected/updated by the function `submitActivator` WHEN it's evaluated in the `button` below

```
<script>
window._alpineSubmitObj = {
    submitDisabled : false,
    submitActivator: (e)=> {
        this.submitDisabled = (e.target.value == "select");
        console.log(this.submitDisabled) // here the value is successfully updated.
        }
    }
</script>
<div x-data="_alpineSubmitObj">
<form method="post" action>

<select x-on:change="submitActivator" name="name">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="A1">A1</option>
  <option value="A2">A2</option>
</select>

<button
x-on:click.prevent="console.log(submitDisabled)" // the value isn't updated, it's always false
x-bind:disabled="this.submitDisabled"
type="submit">Submit
</button>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. The first one is in `submitActivator` method where you bind `this` to the wrong context with the arrow syntax. Using `submitActivator(e) {...}` we access the correct context, so `submitDisabled` can be set. The second error is at the button, when you use `x-bind`, you don't need to add the `this.` prefix to access properties: `x-bind:disabled="submitDisabled"`.

I also provide a more compact version of the problem where I use [`x-model` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#select-inputs) to access the dropdown's value. We can skip using `submitActivator` there.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
window._alpineSubmitObj = {
    submitDisabled : false,
    submitActivator(e) {
        this.submitDisabled = (e.target.value == "select");
        console.log(this.submitDisabled)
    }
}
</script>
<div x-data="_alpineSubmitObj">
<div x-text="`Value of submitDisabled: ${submitDisabled}`"></div>
<form method="post" action>

<select x-on:change="submitActivator" name="name">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="A1">A1</option>
  <option value="A2">A2</option>
</select>

<button x-on:click.prevent="console.log(submitDisabled)"
        x-bind:disabled="submitDisabled"
        type="submit">Submit
</button>

</form>
</div>


<h2>Using x-model</h2>
<div x-data="{selector: 'select'}">
  <select x-model="selector">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="A1">A1</option>
    <option value="A2">A2</option>
  </select>
  
  <button :disabled="selector == 'select'" type="submit">Submit</button>  
</div>
```